# Adding a link to an article to footer in Joomla 1.7

Tags: links, joomla, footer

I need to create a link in footer of my template (for example a TOS link). My footer has a position.

How can I create such a link in Joomla 1.7? Which module can do this?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue.

What I did was made the page an article (i.e. TOS > as an article). Then I made a hidden menu in the menu manager (called it HiddenMenu). I added the TOS page as an item in the menu. This then allows you to link via either a custom HTML module or entering directly into the `index.php` of the template (which ever way you have gone about the footer).

so your HTML will then be: `<a href="/../tos">Terms of Service</a>` assuming you called your article TOS.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Joomla Administrator (your-site/administrator) -> Extensions -> Module Manager.

Click "New", select "Custom HTML", then select "Next".

In the module details specify:
Show Title: Hide
Position: copyright
Custom Output: (the desired footer content)

Save your changes.